# Batch: create fileC.txt from the result of (fileA.txt minus fileB.txt)

Tags: windows, batch-file, foreach

I'm trying to create a batch that creates a fileC.txt containing all lines in fileA.txt except for those that contains the strings in the lines in fileB.txt:

Pseudo:

```
foreach(line L in fileA.txt)
     excluded = false
     foreach(string str in fileB.txt)
          if L contains str 
               exclude = true
     if !excluded
          add L to fileC.txt
```

if L !contains

For example

**fileA.txt:** (all)

```
this\here\is\a\line.wav
and\this\is\another.wav
i\am\a\chocolate.wav
peanut\butter\jelly\time.wav
```

**fileB.txt:** (those to be excluded)

```
another.wav
time.wav
```

**fileC.txt:** (wanted result)

```
this\here\is\a\line.wav
i\am\a\chocolate.wav
```

I've been fiddling around with FINDSTR but I just can't seem to puzzle it together.. any help or pointers greatly appreciated!

Cheers!
/ Fredde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be this simple:

```
findstr /lvg:"fileB.txt" "fileA.txt" >fileC.txt
```

And with your example, the above does give the correct results.

But there is a nasty FINDSTR bug that makes it unreliable when using multiple case sensitive literal search strings. See [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921253/why-doesnt-this-findstr-example-with-multiple-literal-search-strings-find-a-mat), as well as the answer that goes with it. For a "complete" list of undocumented FINDSTR features and bugs, see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman).

So the simple code above can fail depending on the content of the files. If you can get away with using a case insensitive search, then the solution is simple.

```
findstr /livg:"fileB.txt" "fileA.txt" >fileC.txt
```

***Edit:*** *Both versions above will fail if fileB.txt contains `\\` or `\"`. In order to work properly, those strings must be escaped as `\\\` and `\\"`*

But if you must use a case sensitive search, then there is no simple solution. Your best bet for a pure batch solution might be to use the /R regular expression option. But then you will have to create a modified version of fileB.txt where all regex meta-characters are escaped so that the strings give the correct literal search. That is a mini project in and of itself.

Perhaps your best option for a case sensitive solution is to get a 3rd party tool like grep or sed for Windows.

***Edit: Here is a reasonably performing pure batch solution that is nearly bullet proof***

I looked into doing something like the proposed logic in your question. But using batch to read all lines in a file is relatively slow. This solution only reads the exclude file line by line. It uses FINDSTR to read the lines in "fileA.txt" repeatedly, once per search string. This is a much faster algorithm for a batch file.

The traditional method to read a file is to use a FOR /F loop, but there is another technique using SET /P that is faster, and it is safe to use with delayed expansion. The only limitations to this method are:

- It strips trailing control characters from the line
- It is limited to 1021 bytes per line
- Each line must be terminated by `<CR><LF>` as is the Windows standard. It will not work with unix style lines terminated by `<LF>`

The search strings must have each `\` and `"` escaped as `\\` and `\"` when they are used with the /C option.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
copy fileA.txt fileC.txt >nul
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<fileB.txt') do set len=%%N
<fileB.txt (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 !len!) do (
    set "ln="
    set /p "ln="
    if defined ln (
      set "ln=!ln:\=\\!"
      set ln=!ln:"=\"!
      move /y fileC.txt temp.txt >nul
      findstr /lv /c:"!ln!" temp.txt >fileC.txt
    )
  )
)
del temp.txt
type fileC.txt
```

Comment: Incredibly elaborate and satisfying answer! Even though your first solution was sufficient in my case* I very much enjoyed reading your entire post! I would upvote it if I could and will when I can! 

I bow before you, o wise dbenham!
Thanks :)

*pun intended