# Find 2 values in file with command-line | CMD

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

This code below allows me to find the word "error" in all my files using command-line (CMD).

```
find /c "error" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

But I want it to look for the word "**error**" and "**warning**" at the same time.

So I want to put these 2 lines in as 1 line of command.

```
find /c "error" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
find /c "warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

I do not want to see 2 result sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work (`FINDSTR` splits the search string at spaces, so it looks for either word).

```
findstr "error warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

As should this equivalent search:

```
findstr /c:"error" /c:"warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

However, there is this bug: [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053). I'm not sure if the above searches would meet the criteria that specify when the bug *might* affect the results. (I'm not sure if there enough overlap between the search strings.) But better to be safe than sorry.

You can eliminate the possibility of the bug by either making the search case insensitive (not sure if that meets your requirements or not):

```
findstr /i "error warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

or you can convert your search strings into regular expressions. This is trivial to implement in your case since there are no regex meta-characters that need escaping in your search strings.

```
findstr /r "error warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case you could simple use a pipe for realize the *AND* operator.

```
find /c "error" C:\MyFiles\*.txt | find /c "warning"
```

**From your comment, you need an `OR` operator**

In this case I would do the search with `findstr` and the counting with `find /c`

```
findstr "error warning" C:\MyFiles\*.txt | find /c /v ""
```

Comment: This does work thanks, but if I have 4 "warning" messages and 2 "error" messages in the same file. It only shows a count of the 4. It must show a count of 6 because of the 4 + 2.

Comment: The code above only shows lines with both words in. A typical `AND`. But it seems that you need an `OR` solution.

Comment: Thanks, correct, but I would still need to specify the file path C:\MyFiles\*.txt

Comment: It works for me and a small sample file, you could post a snippet of your data file

Comment: If I make the code to look at only 1 file with only the word error in it still does not work hey.

Comment: @Etienne - jeb misunderstood your requirement and thought you were trying to get the count of the number of lines that have either word. The solution should be simple - just remove the pipe and the find command from his answer. But... read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11261016/1012053) as to why it might not be that simple.