# Batch file to compare contents of a text file

Tags: file, batch-file, compare

I have two text files which contain the below numbers

```
File1
00000
11111

File2
00000
11111
22222
```

I need a code which compares the contents of file2 to that of file1 and the numbers which are not matched , in this case '22222' be the only content in file2.

In short i want to erase the content of file2 and put the non matched content in file2. Below is the code i have tried but it just erases the entire thing in the file2.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (file1) do (type file2 | findstr /v %%a > file2)

pause
```

Bottom line i need to achieve the below results

```
File1
00000
11111

File2
22222
```

Help please !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the job. It hinges around using  `findstr /m`  option and errorlevels.

Also it writes to a temporary file during processing (and cleans it).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Stripping duplicates in file2 (%2) compared to lines in file1 (%1)

if not exist "%1" (
  echo That first file doesn't exist.
  exit /b 1
)

if not exist "%2" (
  echo That second file doesn't exist.
  exit /b 2
)

REM Create empty temporary file
echo. 2> %2.tmp

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (%2) do (
  echo Processing %%a
  >nul call findstr /m "%%a" %1
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo OK
    >> %2.tmp echo %%a
  ) else (
    echo Duplicate!
  )
)


echo Writing results to %2
xcopy /y /q %2.tmp %2
del /q %2.tmp
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the simplest and fastest native batch solution

```
findstr /vixg:"File1" "File2" >"File2.new"
move /y "File2.new" "File2"
```

Note that I used the `findstr /i` case insensitive option. This is important because of a [findstr bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053) that can lead to missed matches when searching for multiple literal strings unless the `/i` or `/r` options are used. The case insensitive workaround should not impact you since you are dealing with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Different approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for /f %%i in (file1) do set %%i=%%i
for /f %%j in (file2) do if not defined %%j echo %%j
```

It has following characteristics: 

- scans each of the files only **once**

- duplicates in file1 will be effectively ignored

- you may load file1 into memory and then run several file_x against it to test.

**Notes:** 

I simply echo unique nums to console, you need to change to to write to file

Assumes you compare **words** and there is **one word per line**

It's limited by **maximum number of variables possible to define**. I have no clue what that number is... I tried it with 20 000 lines in file1 (so 20 000 vars defined)

Answer (score -1):

This can be one of the solution:

```
findstr /V /G:file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: This answer introduces nothing new compared to answer from 4 years prior, except for bugs - 1) Lack of `/I` option exposes FINDSTR bug dealing with multiple search terms, 2) Lack of `/X` option allows `2` to match `123`, 3) Doesn't address overwriting file2.txt with the results.