# Using findstr with regular expressions to search sections of a string

Tags: string, batch-file, expression, findstr

I have created code which loops through each line of `files.txt` and identifies if the file is `car`, `boat` or `neither` and stores this information into `SendType.txt`. This is accomplished by using the `findstr` command and searching through the list of `boat.txt` and `car.txt`. Essentially the way the code is designed, it will take the first line of `files.txt` and see if it can find the string in `car.txt` (if so `car` is output to `SendType.txt`) if not it will search for the string in `boat.txt` (if the string is found in `boat.txt`, `boat` is output to `SendType.txt`), and if the string is not found in either car.txt or `boat.txt`, then the text `neither` is output to `SendType.txt`

Right now the code searches for the entire string line. Each string is similar to `11111_2222-22_2010-09-09_10-24-20.zip` (`11111`=ID, `2222-22`=model, `2010-09-09`=date, `10-24-20`=transaction ID).

I would like to replace my current findstr line, which searches the entire line, to search for the entire string EXCEPT the date portion. I have attached my code below for reference along with some examples of the files being input. Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%a in (files.txt) do (
findstr %%a car.txt
if errorlevel 1 (
findstr %%a boat.txt
    if errorlevel 1 (
    echo neither >>SendType.txt
) else (
    echo boat >>SendType.txt
)
) else (
    echo car >>SendType.txt
)
)
```

---

```
car.txt
11111_2222-22_2010-09-09_10-24-20.zip
11112_2222-11_2011-11-09_10-24-25.zip
```

---

```
boat.txt
11122_1111-22_2012-04-09_11-29-56.zip
11144_3333-11_2011-12-22_06-29-66.zip
```

---

```
files.txt
11122_1111-22_2000-01-01_11-29-56.zip
11144_3333-11_2000-01-01_06-29-66.zip
11155_1212-12_2000-01-01_11-19-69.zip
11111_2222-22_2000-01-01_10-24-20.zip
11112_2222-11_2000-01-01_10-24-25.zip
12345_2233-12_2000-01-01_07-27-44.zip
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
SendType.txt
boat
boat
neither
car
car
neither
```

---

**UPDATE 10/15 3:00 PM**
The current approach using dbenham's code and the parsing technique is as follows:

```
@echo off    
>SendType.txt (  
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%a in (filenames.txt) do (    
findstr /c:"%%a_%%b_%%d" sneakernet.txt >nul && (echo sneakernet) || (      
findstr /c:"%%a_%%b_%%d" devmed.txt >nul && (echo devmed) || echo tanto   
       ) 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of the IDs is fixed with two `_` that precede the date, then the solution is easy: simply use FOR /F to parse the values.

I like to use `&&` and `||` instead of testing ERRORLEVEL. Also, you don't need the output of FINDSTR, so you can redirect to nul. You should verify that the string matches from the begining of the line. Finally, you only need to redirect once, so you can overwrite instead of append - easier to test repeatedly because no need to delete before start.

```
@echo off
>SendType.txt (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%a in (files.txt) do (
    findstr /bc:"%%a_%%b" car.txt >nul && (echo car) || (
      findstr /bc:"%%a_%%b" boat.txt >nul && (echo boat) || echo neither
    )
  )
)
```

If the format (and possibly length) of the ID can vary, but the format (length) of the date portion is constant, then you can use a substring:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>SendType.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (files.txt) do (
    set "ln=%%a"
    findstr /bc:"!ln:~0,-23!" car.txt >nul && (echo car) || (
      findstr /bc:"!ln:~0,-23!" boat.txt >nul && (echo boat) || echo neither
    )
  )
)
```

If neither the ID nor date format is constant, then I would change the content of boat.txt and car.txt by stripping off the date portion. Then you can use the FINDSTR `/G` option. The `/I` option is needed because of a [bug in FINDSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053).

```
car.txt
11111_2222-22
11112_2222-11
```

---

```
boat.txt
11122_1111-22
11144_3333-11
```

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>SendType.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (files.txt) do (
    echo %%a|findstr /blig:car.txt >nul && (echo car) || (
      echo %%a|findstr /blig:boat.txt >nul && (echo boat) || echo neither
    )
  )
)
```

**Updated answer**

Now that I understand the requirements, this should solve the problem. I've basically used a variation of the 1st code in my original answer, and I've switched to using a regular expression. The test could be made more stringent by substituting `[0-9]` for each `.` in the regex.

```
@echo off
>SendType.txt (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,4 delims=_" %%a in (files.txt) do (
    findstr /brc:"%%a_%%b_....-..-.._%%c" car.txt >nul && (echo car) || (
      findstr /brc:"%%a_%%b_....-..-.._%%c" boat.txt >nul && (echo boat) || echo neither
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. You're ideas work great but there is one catch that I perhaps did not make clear in my original question: There is several sessions in `files.txt` where the `ID` and `model` number are identical, but the transaction is different. (For example, there exists `11122_1111-22_2000-01-01_11-29-56.zip` and `11122_1111-22_2010-04-04_11-29-59.zip`). So the files cannot be assorted by simply using the beginning of the string (with the `ID` and `model`). The `findstr` command must also take into account the `transaction` number.

Comment: I have updated the original question to show the new changes to the code. The `findstr` command does not work properly with the parsing based on the `_` character.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for the example I provided. But when I try your code on my actual data it does not work. The formats are identical to the files I listed, just with different data. I actually did a similar approach with the regular expressions and achieved the same result from your code. Hmmm...at this point it is more of a troubleshooting exercise for me. Thanks a lot for the help, I'll try and dabble around with my data until it works. Excellent answers!

Comment: Final Update: The problem was solved...there was a trailing space at the end of each line in `files.txt` which was causing the findstr command to not work properly. Simple fix =]