# Compare CSV files

Tags: csv, command-line, comparison, command-line-interface

I am currently using a windows utility called [TableTexCompare](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_comparison.html)

This tool can take 2 CSV files and compare them. The nice thing about it is that it can make the comparison even if the records of the 2 files are not sorted in the same order or the fields are not positioned in the same order.

As such, the following 2 files would result in a successful comparison

(File1.csv)

```
FirstName,LastName,Age
Mona,Sax,30
Max,Payne,43
Jack,Lupino,50
```

(File2.csv)

```
FirstName,Age,LastName
Max,43,Payne
Jack,50,Lupino
Mona,30,Sax
```

What I am looking for is to do the same thing from the command-line with just 1 difference:
I would like the comparison to be performed in one direction only, i.e. if File2.csv is as follows (a subset of File1.csv), the comparison should pass

(File2.csv)

```
FirstName,Age,LastName
Jack,50,Lupino
```

I do not particularly care if it's going to be in some programming language, a dedicated cli tool or a shell script (e.g. using awk). I have some experience with Java and Groovy but would like to be pointed to some initial direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can offer a Python solution:

```
import csv
with open("file1.csv") as f1, open("file2.csv") as f2:
    r1 = list(csv.DictReader(f1))
    r2 = csv.DictReader(f2)
    for item in r2:
        if not item in r1: 
            print("r2 is not a subset of r1!")
            break
```

This is actually a bit more verbose than necessary in Python (but easier to understand); I personally would have used a generator expression:

```
import csv
with open("file1.csv") as f1, open("file2.csv") as f2:
    r1 = list(csv.DictReader(f1))
    r2 = csv.DictReader(f2)
    if all(item in r1 for item in r2):
        print("r2 is a subset of r1")
```

Comment: I'm quite impressed at how small and easy-to-read the code in Python is.

Comment: @ArgyriosTzakas: It can be simplified even more; see my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to do a case insensitive comparison, and if there are no duplicates within File2.csv that must be matched within File1.csv, and if File1.csv does not contain `\\` or `\"`, then all you need is a simple FINDSTR command.

The following will list lines in File2.csv that do not appear in File1.csv:

```
findstr /vxig:"File1.csv" "File2.csv"
```

If all you want is an indication whether File1.csv is a superset of File2.csv, then

```
findstr /vxig:"File1.csv" "File2.csv" >nul && (echo File1 is NOT a superset of File2) || (echo File1 IS a superset of File2)
```

The search should not have to be case insensitive, except there is a nasty FINDSTR bug: it may fail to find matches when there are multiple case sensitive literal search strings of varying size. The case insensitive option avoids the bug. See [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053) for more info.

The search will not work properly if File2.csv contains `\\` or `\"` because FINDSTR will treat them as `\` and `"` respectively. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more info. The accepted answer has sections describing FINDSTR escape sequences about half way down.

Comment: It looks like the limitations of findstr do not affect my case, but I just tried the command using the same 2 files I used with the Python script above and I get the wrong result (that File1 is NOT a superset of File2)

Comment: @ArgyriosTzakas - Doh, right you are. I had a silly bug where I incorrectly swapped File1 with File2. I've updated and fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [q - Text as a Database](https://github.com/harelba/q) , which allows executing SQL directly on csv files, including joins. This will allow doing a compare easily, and much more, such as matching specific columns for equality, and getting specific columns from rows that don't match etc.

Full disclosure - It's my own open source tool.

Harel Ben-Attia

Comment: Would love a practical example using your tool to see it in action :)