# Test if a Reg Query is a specific value in a batch script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, findstr

So without getting to convoluted, the gist of what I am trying to accomplish is that I currently am listing the results from a reg query by display name of programs, assigning a number to it, and then calling it later by number.  When it lists the results it then uses a findstr to filter specific programs (such as anything with microsoft in it) from the list because I don't want them to even be an option for uninstalling.  Right now it works basically, except it returns like this:

```
Let's say the programs in the Registry are: 
Microsoft Update (should be filtered)
Notepad
Java
Microsoft Word (should be filtered)
Yahoo Toolbar
```

When I run this:

```
: progList64
cls
set regVar=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
set opt=64
echo _______________________________________________________
echo.
echo Please wait while I compile a list of known programs...
echo _______________________________________________________
echo.
echo %tab%64bit Programs
echo Index%tab%Name
set count=0
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('Reg Query %regVar% /S^|find " DisplayName"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%n in (!count!) do (
        endlocal
        set product[%%n]=%%b
        echo %%n.%tab%%%b | findstr /V /C:"Microsoft" | findstr /V /C:"Dell" | findstr /V /C:"MDOP" | findstr /V /C:"MED"
    )   
)
echo _______________________________________________________
echo.
echo ============ PRESS 'M' TO GO TO MAIN MENU =============
echo.
goto uninstallerMenu
```

I get this:

```
2. Notepad
3. Java
5. Yahoo Toolbar
```

So later when I call from the array you can actually put in 1 or 4 and select that product even though it's not displayed.  I'm trying to filter it before it prints that it only prints what I want, resulting in this:

```
1. Notepad
2. Java
3. Yahoo Toolbar
```

I've tryin using various IF statements, tried putting the entire for %%n in (!count!) part in an IF statement that tests if Microsoft, dell, etc are in the DisplayName and then only displaying and increasing the counter if it fits, but that's not working either.  I'm at my wits end here, any ideas?

And unrelated and not really important, but does anyone know a better way of filtering rather than daiychaining an entire row of findstr statements?  Like an exclude list or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick guess, try, before the `FOR` loop, (say after the `SET COUNT...`)

```
set excluded=Microsoft Dell MDOP MED
```

Then cascade

```
|findstr /v "%excluded%"
```

after the `FIND " Displayname"`

This should filter out any of the space-separated words in `excludeme`

Your existing cascaded `findstr` can then be removed as those names are removed before your inner `for` loop and thus also won't acquire a number.

see
    findstr /?

from the prompt for docco...

Comment: Works great, only issue is there are a couple programs that have spaces in them (ie Configuration Manager Client) which I want to exclude but don't want to exclude every program with the words configuration or manager or client in it.  Also, what about blanks names?  Just use empty quotes?

Comment: cascade a  `findstr /v /i /c:"configuration manager"` after the `..."%excludeme%"`. The `/c` causes `findstr` to look for precisely the words specified - including the space. The /i you may or may not want - makes the test case-insensitive.

Comment: @Flynn - The `/I` option is critical to avoid a nasty FINDSTR bug that can result in missed matches when using multiple search strings. See [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053) and/or [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more info.

Comment: One thing thatstill isn't working though is testing if the string is empty.  All the exclusions work great, but how do you filter out an empty result?  There is some random microsoft program that doesn't have a displayname, so I want to filter it out along with the other names

Comment: You mean that `%%b` may be empty? The way I'd do it would be to add `set dispname=%%b&if defined dispname ` between the `DO` and the `(` in your `for /f...%%a...` This will set `dispname` to [nothing] for the line where there's no display name, hence the `IF DEFINED` will be true only if the display name was found (it works on the RUN-TIME value of the variable). Now - that also assumes that `%%b` is set to [nothing], not one or more spaces...