# Windows Batch - For Loop - NOT IN

Tags: windows, cmd

Most of the examples on using Windows Batch For Loop is about using "IN".

```
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3 4) DO ECHO %%A
```

I need to use NOT IN instead. When I type something as:

```
FOR %%A NOT IN (1 2 3 4) DO ECHO %%A
```

It says "NOT was not expected at that time".

Thanks

Comment: What's *not in* 1..4? 0 then 5..infinity? What's the relationship to powershell?

Comment: That's just an example. I meant how to use NOT IN. I am checking against a text files that lists file names. thanks

Comment: AFAIK NOT is not valid with IN, you could set a variable inside the IN and if its not set after, its NOT IN?

Comment: There is no "NOT IN" feature. There is "IF NOT", but that's all.

Comment: I am looping over a list of files, I want to move all files in a directory that are NOT  IN the list of file names in the text file. Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

according to your comments above, you want to have a "DIR without those files"? 
Then this should work:

**> type donotuse.txt**

```
alpha.txt
beta.exe
gamma.cmd
```

**> type t.bat**

```
@dir /b | findstr /b /e /v /i /l /g:donotuse.txt
```

**> dir /b**

```
albetade.txt
alpha.exe
alpha.txt
beta.exe
donotuse.txt
gamma.cmd
t.bat
```

**> t**

```
albetade.txt
alpha.exe
donotuse.txt
t.bat
```

>

**edit**: dbenham is right. Added `/i /l` to my code.

Comment: Very close, but you need the `/L` option to force literal interpretation of names instead of regex. You also need the `/I` option to force case insensitive matching. On general principal, you should use `/I` when working with Windows file names. But it is actually critical in this case to avoid a nasty FINDSTR bug. See [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053)

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "somepath\*"^|findstr /vilxg:"exclusions.txt"') do echo %%F
```

Since in comments you say you want to move files not in a list, you should try using `ROBOCOPY`. Check out the `/MOV` and `/XF` options. It should allow you to do exactly what yo want in a more direct manner. Type `robocopy /?` from the command line for help. There are a ton of options to navigate, so it might take a while to get the exact result you want. But the command is extremely powerful and worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Bill, this might do what you need, or give you a hint...

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' type "file.txt" ') do (
if not exist "c:\target\%%a" move "%%a" "c:\target"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but no solution.
So... that's my personal, simple, solution:

```
@echo off
rem set the path to check
set sourcePath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware
set destPath=c:\temp\MySoftware-StrangerFiles
set tempPath=c:\temp
set currentFilesListTxtFileName=MySoftware-allfiles.txt
set correctFilesListTxtFileName=MySoftware-correctFilesList.txt
set moveFilesListTxtFileName=MySoftware-moveFilesList.txt
echo Move not allowed files in a different path
cd "%sourcePath%"
mkdir %destPath%

call :correctFilesList

dir /B > c:\temp\MySoftware-allfiles.txt
findstr /V /G:%tempPath%\%correctFilesListTxtFileName% %tempPath%\%currentFilesListTxtFileName% > %tempPath%\%moveFilesListTxtFileName%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' type "%tempPath%\%moveFilesListTxtFileName%" ') do move %%a %destPath%
pause

:correctFilesList
rem files whitelist
rem correctfiles can be changed with "dir /B path>>c:\temp\correctFilesList.txt" from a correct source. Or you can generate a list of correct files via command as below.
echo correctfile1.dll>> %tempPath%\%correctFilesListTxtFileName%.txt
echo correctfile2.log.xml>> %tempPath%\%correctFilesListTxtFileName%.txt
echo correctfile2.log.xml>> %tempPath%\MySoftware-correctFilesList.txt
```