# How to get serial number from bios and compare it with a set of other serial number using Windows batch command?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of 100+ serial number.
What I want to do is: checking if the serial number of the computer I'm working on is in the list.
Is it possible to do this in Windows batch script ?

Comment: Sounds like a FOR /D loop would make sense here.  How is the list of serial numbers stored?  If it's in a file you can iterate through each entry and check if there's a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to iterate through every line in the file:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do ( 
  findstr "%%s" serials.txt
  )
if %errorlevel%==0 ( echo Serialnumber found ) else ( echo Serialnumber not listed )
```

Answer (score 1):

This command-line show the BIOS SerialNumber in my computer (Windows 8):

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %s in ('wmic bios list BRIEF') do echo %s
```

You may test it and adjust it until get what you want. For example:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('wmic bios list BRIEF') do set serial=%%s
for /F "delims=" %%s in (serialList.txt) do if "%%s" equ "%serial%" goto found
echo Not found
goto :EOF

:found
echo OK
```

**EDIT**: I modified the program in order to include the serial numbers in the Batch file; I also used the modification in `wmic` parameters suggested by Stephan:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do set serial=%%s
for %%s in (serial0 serial1 serial2 serial3 serial4 serial5 serial6 serial7 serial8 serial9
            ser90 ser91 ser92 ser93 ser94 ser95 ser96 ser97 ser98 ser99 ser100 ser101) do (
   if "%%s" equ "%serial%" goto found
)
echo Not found
goto :EOF

:found
echo OK
```

Comment: Is it possible if i want to put the S/Ns inside the batch file rather than put it in a file ?

Comment: Of course, this is just an example of what may be done... However, it is more convenient to write 100+ serial numbers in a text file.

Comment: your `for` echoes "American" at my computer. Use `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %s in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do echo %s`instead.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a FOR loop if you use your list as the search strings and WMIC BIOS output as the target. I believe the serial number is always 10 characters, so no `/I` option is needed. But if the serial number length can vary, then the `/I` option is required due to a FINDSTR bug: [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053)

```
wmic bios get serialNumber|findstr /blg:list.txt&&echo number found||echo number not listed
```

You can suppress the output of the serial number to the screen by redirecting the FINDSTR output to nul using `>nul`.