# Batch to read File1 line by line and remove them from File2 if a matching line is found

Tags: batch-file

So I have File1.txt with content

```
aaa
ccc
```

..and File2.txt with content

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want to delete from File2.txt all lines that are also found in File1.txt.  So in this example File2 will be left with only one row, "bbb" .

How can I achieve this with a batch file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
    REM We have to introduce a third file because we can't use the type command redirects its output to itself. this would result in an empty file
    if exist file3.txt del file3.txt
    TYPE file2.txt |find /i /v "%%a">file3.txt
    COPY /y file3.txt file2.txt
)
```

This only works if the files do not quote chars (") because this might screw up the quoting of `find /i /v "%%a"`
The magic lies in the `/v` switch of the `find` command. it only shows lines which do not contain the requested string.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is looking for exact matches, in which case this will fail if File2 contains `aaaa` because FIND will match `aaa` to `aaaa`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to ignore case when comparing strings, then there is a simple solution using FINDSTR.

```
findstr /vlixg:"file1.txt" "file2.txt" >"file2.txt.new"
move /y "file2.txt.new" "file2.txt" >nul
```

The above will not work properly if File1.txt contains `\\` or `\"`. Such strings would have to be escaped as `\\\` (or `\\\\`) and `\\"` (or `\\\"`) .

The reason the search must ignore case is because of a nasty FINDSTR bug: [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053)

Below is a robust, case sensitive, but slow, pure native batch solution that reads lines from File1 one line at a time, and removes that line from File2. It uses a temporary file to hold the search string. It could be done using a search string on the command line, except there is an obscure case involving `\\` and `\"` characters that is problematic. See the section titled *Escaping Backslash within command line literal search strings* within [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053) for more information.

The odd FOR /F syntax is used to disable the EOL and DELIMS options. The USEBACKQ option is only added in case you change the file name to a name with spaces. The toggling of delayed expansion is used to protect `!` characters that may be within File1.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("File1.txt") do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  (echo(!ln:\=\\!)>"File1.txt.new"
  endlocal
  findstr /vlxg:"File1.txt.new" "File2.txt" >"File2.txt.new"
  move /y "File2.txt.new" "File2.txt" >nul
)
del "File1.txt.new" 2>nul
```

Finally, if you are willing to use some hybrid scripting, than the following is robust, and it is very efficient. It relies on a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) to escape all regex meta characters within File1.

```
@echo off
type "File1.txt"|repl "([[\\.*^$])" \$1 >"File1.txt.new"
findstr /vrxg:"File1.txt.new" "File2.txt" >"File2.txt.new"
move /y "File2.txt.new" "File2.txt" >nul
del "File1.txt.new"
```