# Batch Script - Deleting specific lines from a text file

Tags: batch-file, automation

Suppose there are two files Temp1 & Temp2 containing below data =

Temp1.txt:

```
xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
yyyyy yyyy yyy yyyyyyy yyyy yyy
zz zzzzz zz zzzz zzz zzz zz z z
```

Temp2.txt :

```
xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
zz zzzzz zz zzzz zzz zzz zz z z
aaaa aa aaaa aa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa
```

The requirement is to delete (in Temp1) the lines which are matching with Temp2. And possibly save it in a different file.
So, basically the output should be something like this :

Temp.txt :

```
yyyyy yyyy yyy yyyyyyy yyyy yyy
```

This is what i have got so far :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A IN ('type "Temp2.txt"') DO (
    SET STRING=%%A
    FINDSTR /V /C:%STRING% "Temp1.txt" > Temp.txt
)
```

But, i think this code will keep the matching data, instead of deleting. Needs correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINDSTR by itself ought to be a great solution. Reading the documentation, one would think the following literal search should work.

```
findstr /vlxg:"temp2.txt" "temp1.txt" >temp.txt
```

But the following [FINDSTR bugs and limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) prevent the above from being reliable

- [Specifying multiple literal search strings can fail to find all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253/1012053) (bug)
- Literal searches may require `\` and/or `"` to be escaped as `\\` and `\"`

The solution is to do a regular expression search instead. But this requires that regular expression meta characters within temp2.txt must be escaped. This is a perfect task for my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "[.*^$[\\]" "\$&" /f "temp2.txt"|findstr /rvxg:/ "temp1.txt" >"temp.txt"
```

The above works as follows.

The JREPL command escapes meta characters within temp2.txt and the output is piped to FINDSTR

The FINDSTR /R option treats all search strings as regular expressions

The /V option causes matching lines to be suppressed, and non matching lines are printed

The /X option means a search string must match the entire line

The /G:/ option instructs FINDSTR to read the search strings from stdin (the pipe)

The JREPL | FINDSTR solution has the following limitations, all due to FINDSTR behavior

- All lines in temp2.txt must be <= 511 characters, even after the meta characters have been escaped
- All lines in temp1.txt must be terminated by \r\n (carriage return linefeed)
- \r must not appear anywhere within temp1.txt other than at the end of a line.

The limitations can be eliminated and the solution is much simpler if you download [GNU grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) - a port of the standard unix utility.

```
grep -x -v -F -f "temp2.txt" "temp1.txt" >"temp.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't even need a script for this. It's a single command:

```
findstr /x /v /G:temp2.txt temp1.txt >temp.txt
```

`/x` compares whole lines

`/v` prints only lines, that do NOT match

`/g` uses a file (temp2.txt) to get the searchstrings

Comment: This ought to work with the addition of the /L switch, but it is unreliable! See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29520063/1012053) as to why a simple FINDSTR command cannot be used.