# findstr does not find "NOW"

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I don't have a lot of experiences with **findstr** but this is not understandable for me at all. Or is it a bug of findstr?

look at these examples:

1) `echo NOW|findstr "CLEAN NOCHANGE NOW">NUL&&echo found`
return nothing  But why??

2) `echo CLEAN|findstr "CLEAN NOCHANGE NOW">NUL&&echo found`
return found   here it's ok

3) `echo NOCHANGE|findstr "CLEAN NOCHANGE NOW">NUL&&echo found`
return found   this also work

But when I use /I it works
4) `echo NOW|findstr /I "CLEAN NOCHANGE NOW">NUL&&echo found`
-> return found  its ok

if 'now' is lowercase -> it works
5) `echo now|findstr "CLEAN NOCHANGE now">NUL&&echo` found
-> return found

Is there something special with string "NOW" ?

Comment: There is nothing special with `NOW`, but there is [much special about findstr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) (it's a microsoft tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the thread [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253), `findstr` does not behave correctly when having multiple literal case-sensitive search strings, which are of different lengths and partially overlapping. Reference also this post: [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868).

Here is a work-around using regular expression search strings as no meta characters are used:

```cmd
echo NOW| findstr /R "CLEAN NOCHANGE NOW" > nul && echo found
```

Here is a work-around using individual `findstr` commands for every single literal search string:

```cmd
echo NOW| (findstr /V "CLEAN" | findstr /V "NOCHANGE" | findstr /V "NOW") > nul || echo found
```

Here is another work-around based on the small sibling of `findstr`, namely the `find` command:

```cmd
echo NOW| (find /V "CLEAN" | find /V "NOCHANGE" | find /V "NOW") > nul || echo found
```