# Findstr /G: does not work in batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I want to see the files that are not in the temporary file 'output.tmp' with this code but it does not work.

```
FOR /f "Delims=" %%A in (
'Dir /B/A-D *.*^|Findstr /VEIL /G:output.tmp'
) Do echo "%%A"
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of the failure?

Comment: Is output.tmp in the same directory as the script?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the same directory

Comment: Try replacing `/VEIL` with `/VXIL`

Comment: Perhaps related: [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253)